# How do you make the react-native react-navigation tab bar transparent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to make the tab bar transparent?  I tried the following but it just showed a white background.  Do I need to implement my own tabBarComponent?  If so, is there any documentation on that class and what interface I need to implement?

```
const MainTabNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    MessageCenter: { screen: MessageCenterStack },
    Camera: { screen: CameraStack },
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor:  'transparent',
      },
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have to set position `absolute` and give it a left right and bottom for it the backgroundColor transparent to take effect.

```
tabBarOptions: {
  showIcon: true,
  showLabel: false,
  lazyLoad: true,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 20,
    height: 100
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle this when using SafeAreaView?

Comment: Nvm just cracked it. Turns out you have to set the SafeAreaView's position to absolute

Comment: Not working in android for me. react navigation v 3.8.1

Comment: If i used position absolute, the others menu ca't be click. how to resolve?

Comment: Check my answer @gamingumar

Comment: massive thanks for giving me a clue by changing the position to absolute, upvoted! I'm making floating button on bottom tab, and now it's work with react navigation 5, if you want to see my result here https://imgur.com/a/o4JJQdm

Comment: Not working on android! :(

Answer (score 18):

position: 'absolute' is a solution for this, but you may notice it'll not look perfectly with the android side, however working perfectly for the android side.

Finally, I found the solution to this after long hard work.

elevation: 0

Set this on tab bar style will fix this issue.

Example -

```
tabBarOptions={{
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: COLORS.tabSelected,
        inactiveTintColor: COLORS.tabNormal, 
        style: {
          backgroundColor:'transparent',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          position: 'absolute',
          elevation: 0  // <-- this is the solution
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
        },
      }}>
```

Here are the output screenshots.
[image: Before set "elevation: 0", it was looking like this]

[image: After set "elevation: 0", it's looking perfect]

Answer (score 16):

I finally got it working on android and ios by adding a container view for the custom tab bar component and make the container absolute positioned and leave the tab bar as it is

**Here is the custom tab bar component**

```
const TabBarComponent = (props) => (<BottomTabBar {...props} />)
```

**Here is the tab bar options**

```
{
    tabBarComponent: props => {
        return (
            <View style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
            }}>
                <TabBarComponent {...props} />
            </View>
        )
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
        style: {
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            height: 55,
            paddingBottom: 5,
        }
    },
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
}
```

**And the final result**

[image: Transparent tab bar with border radius]

Comment: What is BottomTabBar here?

Comment: @JuliGupta it is imported from react-navigation library, used to inherit the default tabbar component

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solved this for react-navigation v6

```
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  BottomTabBar,
} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

We need to use BottomTabBar to customize the layout and make it transparent

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator
      // Here under tabBar we customize the view and set the bg to transparent
      tabBar={props => (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}>
          <BottomTabBar {...props} />
        </View>
      )}>
...
```

If you do it under

```
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
   tabBarStyle:{
     position:absolute,
     ...
   }
 })
}
```

it doesn't work as excpected

Comment: Thanks, this implementation worked for v6

Comment: Yup, this works for v6. `screenOptions` doesn't. Also as a quick note, for me it wasn't refreshing correctly as I changed the code even if hot reload was on and otherwise working for everything else. If you change something, make sure you reload the app if the changes don't get reflected.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of the answers here seem to be a little convoluted for the question. So for others looking how to do so, here's a simple answer:

Within the tab bar options change position to absolute and background colour to transparent such that it looks like:

```
tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **React Navigation v6,** you would want to set up **screenOptions** on the TabNavigator. (I use it in combination with custom / transparent bottom tab bar).

```
import {
  BottomTabBar,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: 'blue'},
      }}
      tabBar={props => {
        return (
          <View>
            <BottomTabBar {...props} />
          </View>
        );
      }}
      initialRouteName={SCREEN_NAMES.APP.HOME_TAB}
      ...
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed Tawfik's answer worked for me but I had to import `<BottomTabBar>`component from `react-navigation-tabs` instead of suggested `react-navigation`.

Answer (score 0):

**In React Navigation v5**

```
tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          elevation: 0, // this solved the triangle type view problem in android
        },
      }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, apply a position of 'absolute,' and then use a background color like this:-

```js
tabBarStyle: {
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',      
              height: 90,
            },
```

Answer (score -1):

actually, It is getting its color from `NavigationContainer` theme backgroundColor you can give transparent color to `NavigationContainer` like this

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const theme = { //like this
    colors: {
      background: "transparent",
    },
  };

<NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
     <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen component={ComponentA} name="A" />
          <Tab.Screen component={ComponentB} name="B" />
     </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple, think about all component rendering placing in-app,

1. header: navigation header
2. body: app content
3. footer: tab-bar

In-app all the above three-component have their own specific place to render one after one like position relative(default).

and where you want to show the tab-bar top of the body (ignoring its position and placing), then you have to bring it on top of the body by styling tabbarOption **"position: 'absolute'",**
now it's working, but one new problem arise, due to position absolute body goes all the way bottom, and some of the body content is hidden behind the tab-bar
to fix that need to add padding or add some dummy  with some height as per bottom tab bar ***inside all body screens***.