# How to handle the SafeArea's background color with Bottom Tab Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

**Current Behavior**

Hi everyone,

I want to set the background color for the Bottom Tab. So I did as below.

```
<Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#FF0000',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FF0000',
        inactiveTintColor:  '#FFFFFF'
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Account"
        component={AccountScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6939811/76062160-b6dfde00-5fb7-11ea-8808-3f2562e90c24.png]

The problem is the SafeArea has a white background

**Expected Behavior**

What I expect is
[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6939811/76062716-cca1d300-5fb8-11ea-926a-acbd42d412dd.png]

So could you tell me how to solve this issue in React Navigation version 5 please?
Thank you!

**Your Environment**

iOS
react-native:                   0.61.5

@react-navigation/native:       ^5.0.5

@react-navigation/bottom-tabs:  ^5.0.5

Comment: I'm running into this myself. Any luck?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

I just set `backgroundColor`

```js
<Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Stack_Main"
    tabBarOptions={{
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
      },
    }}
  >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
screenOptions={({route}) => ({
    tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: '#436332', borderTopColor: '#23321A'},
    tabBarLabelStyle: {
      fontWeight: '600',
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    tabBarActiveTintColor: '#f1c522',
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#f4f1de',
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: '#436332',
    tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: '#436332',
  })}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a option (I don't like but it work) in this answer: [How do you make the react-native react-navigation tab bar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988486/how-do-you-make-the-react-native-react-navigation-tab-bar-transparent/57691721#57691721)

```html
<Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        activeTintColor: theme.primary,
        inactiveTintColor: theme.tintInactiveTabBar,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: theme.backgroundTabBar,
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          borderTopRightRadius: 10,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        },
      }}>...</Tab.Navigator>
```

Put position: absolute and bottom, left and right attributes. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`@react-navigation^v6.x` you need to add `tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red'}` in the `screenOptions` prop.

For example:

```js
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#141E30',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#BBC8D6',
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerTitleStyle: {color: '#BBC8D6'},
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#141E30',
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Icon
              name="th-list"
              size={25}
              color="#BBC8D6"
              style={{paddingVertical: 10}}
            />
          ),
          title: 'ToDos',
          // tabBarBadge: 3,
        }}
        name={HOME}
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Icon
              name="image"
              size={25}
              color="#BBC8D6"
              style={{paddingVertical: 10}}
            />
          ),
          title: 'Floor Plan',
        }}
        name={FLOOR_PLAN}
        component={FloorPlanScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Icon
              name="user-circle-o"
              size={25}
              color="#BBC8D6"
              style={{paddingVertical: 10}}
            />
          ),
          title: 'Profile',
        }}
        name={PROFILE}
        component={ProfileScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```